# Finding c so that sum(x+c) over positives = K

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, scipy

Say I have a 1D array `x` with positive and negative values in Python, e.g.:

```
x = random.rand(10) * 10
```

For a given **positive** value of `K`, I would like to find the offset `c` that makes the **sum** of **positive** elements of the array `y = x + c` equal to `K`.

How can I solve this problem efficiently?

Comment: If you have a -1 in the array and the offset is 2, does the -1+2 count towards the sum?

Answer (score 2):

How about binary search to determine which elements of `x + c` are going to contribute to the sum, followed by solving the linear equation? The running time of this code is O(n log n), but only O(log n) work is done in Python. The running time could be dropped to O(n) via a more complicated partitioning strategy. I'm not sure whether a practical improvement would result.

```
import numpy as np

def findthreshold(x, K):
    x = np.sort(np.array(x))[::-1]
    z = np.cumsum(np.array(x))
    l = 0
    u = x.size
    while u - l > 1:
        m = (l + u) // 2
        if z[m] - (m + 1) * x[m] >= K:
            u = m
        else:
            l = m
    return (K - z[l]) / (l + 1)

def test():
    x = np.random.rand(10)
    K = np.random.rand() * x.size
    c = findthreshold(x, K)
    assert np.abs(K - np.sum(np.clip(x + c, 0, np.inf))) / K <= 1e-8
```

Here's a randomized expected O(n) variant. It's faster (on my machine, for large inputs), but not dramatically so. Watch out for catastrophic cancellation in both versions.

```
def findthreshold2(x, K):
    sumincluded = 0
    includedsize = 0
    while x.size > 0:
        pivot = x[np.random.randint(x.size)]
        above = x[x > pivot]
        if sumincluded + np.sum(above) - (includedsize + above.size) * pivot >= K:
            x = above
        else:
            notbelow = x[x >= pivot]
            sumincluded += np.sum(notbelow)
            includedsize += notbelow.size
            x = x[x < pivot]
    return (K - sumincluded) / includedsize
```

Comment: NumPy comes with a [binary search](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html), so using that might be faster than writing your own.

Comment: Thanks @David What do you mean by `"catastrophic cancellation"`?

Comment: @user2357112 It's possible, but I suspect that it would take longer to materialize the currently implicit array `z - np.arange(1, x.size + 1) * x` than it does to search in Python.

Comment: @user815423426 Evaluate (1e-9 + 1e9) - 1e9 by hand and in a Python interpreter. If I were you, I would copy the assertion from `test()` into the function itself, so that you get a warning if unruly floating point behavior materially impacts the accuracy of the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort `x` in descending order, loop over `x` and compute the required `c` thus far. If the next element plus `c` is positive, it should be included in the sum, so `c` gets smaller.

Note that it might be the case that there is no solution: if you include elements up to `m`, `c` is such that `m+1` should also be included, but when you include `m+1`, `c` decreases and `a[m+1]+c` might get negative.

In pseudocode:

```
sortDescending(x)
i = 0, c = 0, sum = 0
while i < x.length and x[i] + c >= 0
    sum += x[i]
    c = (K - sum) / i
    i++
if i == 0 or x[i-1] + c < 0
    #no solution
```

The running time is obviously `O(n log n)` because it is dominated by the initial sort.